# gccgo -shared symbol lookup using dlsym

Tags: go

I have been trying to use -buildmode=plugin but the .so file is too large.  It's almost ~1MB for a simple file like

```
package main

var URI string

func Eval() bool {
  return (URI == "Yes")
}
```

So an experiment I compiled with gccgo instead of `go build -buildmode=plugin`I ran the command

```
 gccgo -o test.so -fPIC -shared test.go
```

The file size is really small now almost 16Kb.

The question is can I look up symbols in the above .so file using [dlsym](https://github.com/coreos/pkg/blob/main/dlopen/dlopen.go)? Looks like dlsym retrieves C symbols and not Go symbols. Any way to retrieve, set go symbols?

Update:
nm output

```
             U __gcc_personality_v0
                 U getenv
                 U getpagesize
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000002eb3 T __go_init_main
                 U internal..z2fbytealg..types
                 U internal..z2fcpu..import
                 U internal..z2fcpu..types
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
00000000000022d9 T main.Eval
0000000000006d20 D main.Eval..f
00000000000024bd T main.struct.4runtime.gList.2.runtime.n.0int32.5..eq
0000000000006d28 D main.struct.4runtime.gList.2.runtime.n.0int32.5..eq..f
0000000000002760 T main.struct.4Size.0uint32.2Mallocs.0uint64.2Frees.0uint64.5..eq
0000000000006d30 D main.struct.4Size.0uint32.2Mallocs.0uint64.2Frees.0uint64.5..eq..f
0000000000006d40 D main..types
0000000000007150 D main.URI
                 U malloc
                 U memcmp
00000000000000b8 B __morestack_current_segment
0000000000000000 B __morestack_initial_sp
00000000000000c0 B __morestack_segments
                 U protect
```

Fn Call:

```
sym := s
eval, err := h.GetSymbolPointer(sym)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Didn't find it ")
    return -1, fmt.Errorf("Unable to find symbol")
}
x := (*func() bool)(eval)
test := (*x)()         //Panics here straight away
_ = test

return 0, nil
```

}

Comment: There are no "C-symbols" and "Go-symbols", use command `nm -D test.so` to find out the names of dynamically exported symbols.

Comment: able to see the variable but cannot find it using dlsym, the same code works if I write test.c equivalent to the above snippet and then lookup with dlsym. Not sure what I'm missing

Comment: I think I found the issue, Instead of main.URI I was looking up eval.URI, thanks for the help

Comment: Just another question here, Can we call functions defined in the .so file? Am I supposed to do something to call these functions?

Comment: You mean inter-language call (C->Go or Go->C)?

Comment: The "Eval" fn is a Go function, can I call it? It's a Go func. I can set/get the URI variable easily. But the fn call panics straight away